# Antd RangePicker cannot set 12 hour format for Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Antd RangePicker for showing date range with Time.

By default, the time is the 24hr format. I need to show time in 12hr format.
How can I set time in 12-hour format?

```
<RangePicker
    disabledDate={this.disabledDate}
    showTime={{
    format: 'HH:mm',
    hideDisabledOptions: true,
    defaultValue: [moment('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss'), moment('11:59:59', 
    'HH:mm:ss')],
    }}
    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
  />
```

I have tried options like:

> *use12Hours = {true}*

But nothing worked for me. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Ant Design uses `momentjs` and so you should be able to use the  `format: 'hh:mm'` you may want to add an A, as in `format: 'hh:mm A'` in order to display the AM/PM time to ensure you do not confuse the person reading the time.

In addition to this you have FORMAT specified twice in your config.

You can read more about displaying times in momentjs here:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: But you can't change time picker https://imgur.com/a/mUJV4rB
Always will be  24 hours,  I can  see  on the top  only 12 hours format

Answer (score 1):

```
 <RangePicker
  showTime={{ format: 'hh:mm A', use12Hours:true }}
/>
```

Add 'use12Hours:true' to showTime to change the time picker format.